# Will this method of JavaScript object differentiation work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find new data uploaded to a database, this is the logic it follows:

Read data from my Mongo database store as `d1` >> Pull new data from sql server, store as `d2` >> filter the data and overwrite my Mongo database >> compare `d1` and `d2` to find new documents uploaded.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
diffJSON(d1, d2);

function diffJSON(obj1, obj2) {

    for(document in obj2) {
       if ((obj1.includes(obj2[document]))) {
           //no new data
        };
        else {
            console.log(obj2[document])
        };
    };
};
```

My thinking is that `obj2` will have more data than `obj1` so there must be some data not included in `obj1`, right?

I have also loaded in `d1` and `d2` without the `_id` key, otherwise every document would be different.

Thanks for any help, it is appreciated.

Comment: From the variable names, it sounds like `obj1` is a plain object, not an array, in which case `obj1.includes` wouldn't work..? If you mean to call `diffJSON` with arrays, probably better to indicate that

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah okay, so the `.include()` function only works on arrays?

Comment: yes, `.includes` is a property of array object, so it's not a matter of it working on arrays, it's a matter of only arrays have that method, so the code you have written should state something like `includes is not a function`

Comment: @JaromandaX I think I'm being slow, I don't quite understand...I haven't written `includes is not a function`

Comment: sorry, I don't know where that sentence went wrong, I think I was typing on auto ot something... I should've said "so the code you have written would result in something like the error `includes is not a function`" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX ah cool, no it doesn't.. I just tried some more stuff, it just won't go into my `else` statement

Comment: If you are looking for JavaScript array differentiation tool, why don't you use lodash? Such as https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#difference

Comment: post sample for `obj1` and `obj2`